# Make regExp basing on data

Tags: javascript, regex, dictionary

I'm making application that will recognize human speak plans like `"Each 2 weeks check car before 6p.m"` or `"run for 2 hours"`

It can be written in any correct form, both as numbers or as words (6 can be 6 or "six").

I've made some dictionary and some rules

Part of dictionary and rules:

```
plan.rules = {
    language : "EN", 
    dictionary : {
        numbers : {
            ones : [
                ["zero"], 
                ["one", "first", "once"],
                ["two", "second", "twice"],
                ["three", "third", "thrice"],
                ["four", "fourth"],
                ["five", "fifth"],
                ["six", "sixth"],
                ["seven", "seventh"],
                ["nine", "nineth"]
            ],
            teens : [
                [],
                ["ten", "tenth"],
                ["eleven", "eleventh"],
                ["twelwe", "twelweth"],
                ["fourteen", "fourteenth"],
                ["fiveteen", "fiveteenth"],
                ["sixteen", "sixteenth"],
                ["seventeen", "seventeenth"],
                ["eightteen", "eightteenth"],
                ["nineteen", "nineteenth"],
            ],
            tens : [
                [],
                ["ten"],
                ["twenty"],
                ["thirty"],
                ["fourtu"],
                ["fifty"],
                ["sixty"],
                ["seventy"],
                ["eighty"],
                ["ninety"],
            ]
        },
        peroids : {
            minute : ["min", "minute", "minutes"],
            hour : ["hour", "hours"],
            day : ["day", "days"],
            week : ["week", "weeks"],
            month : ["month", "months"],
            year : ["year", "years"]
        }
    },
    rules : {
        each : [
            "each {peroid}",
            "each {number} {peroid}",
            "every {peroid}",
            "every {number} {peroid}",

        ],
        for : [
            "for {peroid}",
            "for {number} {peroid}"
        ]
    }
}
```

So basing on above data for example `"Each two weeks check something"` :

- `"two"` match **number** 2
- `"weeks"` match **peroid** "week"

so sentence match pattern `"each {number} {peroid}"`

I'm trying to make some algorythm to analize input and I'm thinking about huge loops running dictionary and rules, but maybe is it possible to build some regExp basing on so many cases?

If I'm totally doing it wrong, how could it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a regular expression, but I think that you will get some very unruly regular expressions.

Just as an example: if your text will always have the word `each` followed by some text and a `number` and some text and a `period` you can try to do something like this (you would need more number combinations if you decided to expand this):

`[Ee]ach.*(one|first|1|two|second|2).*(minute?|hour?|day?|week?|month?|year?)`

`Each two weeks check something` matches `two` and `week`

and

`Each first day check something else` matches `first` and `day`

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/dB9fQ4).

**However**, `Each first day of the week do something` or `Each 3rd week of the month do something` will not work.

Using natural language there are so many possible ways to say `each {number} {period}` that using regular expressions would be very difficult to use if you want to catch everything.

Comment: Thats why I'm using dictionary. First I want to 'unify' sentence, replace 'weeks' with week, 'seventh' with 7 etc so I make final check with some 'universal' one.